# Extjs and Spring success handler

Tags: excel, spring, extjs, extjs4

I'm building web application with ExtJs and Spring. With ExtJs I'm uploading excel file and with spring I parse it. Everything works fine, although my success handler in ExtJs code doesn't work. I read many examples about that, but I still can't solve this problem. I hope you guys will help me.

This is ExtJs upload file function:

```
uploadFile: function(value, fld){
    var me = this;
    var id = this.getTipasCombobox().getValue();
    var record = this.getTipasCombobox().getStore().getById(id);
    var timeId = this.getLaikotarpiaiCombo().getValue();
    var timeRecord = this.getLaikotarpiaiCombo().getStore().getById(timeId);
    var fp = this.getUploadBtn().up('form').getForm();
    if(fp.isValid()){
        fp.submit({
            url: Turtas.Properties.getServicePath()+'/save/' + record.data.resource,
            waitMsg: 'Failas yra įkeliamas, prašome palaukti...',
            success: function(){
                console.log("Upload completed");
                me.storeSelection(record.data.resource, timeRecord.data.open, timeRecord.data.year, true, me.restrictedPage())
            }   
        })
    }       
},
```

And this is my controller function which I use to parse Excel:

```
@RequestMapping(value="turtas/save/gelezinkeliai", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveGelezinkeliaiFromExcel(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
    if (file.getSize() != 0){
        ReadExcelFileToList excelFile = new ReadExcelFileToList();
        List<Gelezinkeliai> gelezinkeliai = new ArrayList<Gelezinkeliai>();
        gelezinkeliai = excelFile.readExcelData(/*fileName*/ file);
        gelezinkeliai.remove(0);
        Laikotarpis laikotarpis = new Laikotarpis();
        laikotarpis = laikotarpiaiService.findById(2014);

        for (GelezinkeliaiRest delGelezinkelis : service.getItems(2014, true, false)){
            service.delete(delGelezinkelis);
        }
        List<Gelezinkeliai> finalGelezinkeliai = new ArrayList<Gelezinkeliai>();
        for (Gelezinkeliai gelezinkelis : gelezinkeliai){
            gelezinkelis.setLaikotarpis(laikotarpis);
            finalGelezinkeliai.add(gelezinkelis);
            GelezinkeliaiRest gelezinkeliaiRest = new GelezinkeliaiRest();
            gelezinkeliaiRest.fromGelezinkeliai(gelezinkelis);
            service.save(gelezinkeliaiRest, false);
        }
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        return "{\"success\":true}";
    }
    else {
        return "{\"success\":false}";
    }

}
```

Response content-type is text/html and response is:

```
{"success":true}
```

If I manually reload page or store, data is updated, so functions work properly, but i want to catch event when the request ends, to reload store automatically. I have no idea what's wrong. Thanks for responses in advance!

Comment: *"success handler in ExtJs code doesn't work"* - code throws an exception, doesn't get executed or doesn't do what you'd expect it to do? The easiest way to investigate would be to use your browser's dev tools: check network traffic and set breakpoints in your JS code.

Comment: Thanks for response. I want to know the moment when the request ends, because then I need to reload my store. Success handler would be a great solution. I don't understand what i do wrong, because my success handler doesn't react.

Comment: And code doesn't throw an exception, it does execute and it does everything what I expect it to do, I just want to know the moment when I can reload my store.